# python- robot time setting change

Tags: python, json, windows, selenium, pycharm

i have a ready code and run it via pycharm
I don't have much information about coding and I have two questions:

1:
In the code written after 3 hours and 45 minutes, all accounts from DU 1 to DU 10 log out and re-login. How can I change this amount of time and change it to every 1 hour, for example? I can't find any such time to change?

2:
In this section, the time code for the refresh of chrome pages set for every 30 Minuets, how can I change this refresh time to every 20 minutes? I've changed the wrote time several times in this section
(if mn == 20 or mn == 50:
DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.app.refresh(),)
but I think it doesn't work properly and they're more than of the pages. Thank you for your help, dear friends.

lot of the code :

while True:

```
# round number before changing accounts
a = 45
for k in range(a):
    k += 1
    if k == a:
        print("-----------------------------------------------------")
        print("Lets sign out and change Accounts After 4 Hours ")
        print("-----------------------------------------------------")
        sleep(5)
        
        sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.login()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.app.sign_out()
        sleep(1)
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.app.login()
    else:
        pass
        
    tm = datetime.now()
    tm = tm - timedelta(minutes=tm.minute % 5,
                        seconds=tm.second,
                        microseconds=tm.microsecond)

    year, month, day, mn, hr = tm.year, tm.month, tm.day, tm.minute, tm.hour

    if mn == 55:
        if hr == 23:
            sleep(300)
            mn = 5
            hr = 0
        else:
            mn = 0
            hr = hr + 1
    else:
        mn = mn + 5

    if mn == 20 or mn == 50:
        DU2.DU3.DU4.DU5.DU6.DU7.DU8.DU9.DU10.app.refresh()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. And why so you use variables like `DU1.DU2....` - better create readable names. And if you want to create many variables then maybe you should use list - and `DU[1]` , `DU[2]`, etc. Maybe use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: thanks for answering. this is a code for monitoring appointment website with auto refresh google chrome tabs and accounts . its not completed code i just want know how can change times for sign out sign in and refresh times

Comment: I still don't know what this code is doing but I would chech what is in variables.

Comment: do you can help me ? i realy want help and i dont know how i should do it ;( i just want change log out log in time to accounts from 4 hours to every 1 hours but cant find where is it

Comment: I can't help you because I totally don't understand your code.

Comment: I can only suggest: maybe use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing. You can also use `print()` to display time - to see how long takes some functions.

Comment: thank you so much ,, just can tell me where i should try this codes ?  use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.)

Comment: use everywhere, you can even put after every line of code - to see how it works step-by-step. OR learn how to use real `debuger.